# Split by space, but get newline as a separate entity

Tags: javascript, split

How can I split by space on sentences, but preserve newline (`\n`) character as a separate word?

Input:

```
I am a sentence.\nBefore me, there is a newline. I would like this sentence to be the following:\n\n Look below
```

Output:

```
Array: ['I', 'am', 'a', 'sentence.', '\n', 'Before', 'me,', 'there', 'is', 'a', 'newline.', 'I', 'would', 'like', 'this', 'sentence', 'to', 'be', 'the', 'following:', '\n', '\n', 'Look', 'below'
```

Comment: Split by lines, split each line by spaces, join the lists with newline characters. Although be careful with portability regarding `\r`. See [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```js
var str = `I am a sentence.\nBefore me, there is a newline. I would like this sentence to be the following:\nLook below`;

var res = str.split(/ |(\n)/g).filter(i => i);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: A question: what does mean `(i => i)`? I don't know this expression.

Comment: @reporter, that is *arrow function*, filtering out the `undefined` items from `split()`..:)

Answer (score 2):

You could add spaces after and before the newline:

```
const newString = oldString.replace(/\n/g, ' \n ');
```

And then split by spaces:

```
const result = newString.split(' ');
```